# How to combine an interface and struct in golang?

Tags: go, inheritance, interface, encapsulation

```
package main


type A interface {
    GetName() string
}

type B struct {
    A
}

func (this *B) Func1() {
    this.GetName()
}

type C struct {
    B
}

func (this *C) GetName() string {
    return "hello"
}


func main() {
    var c = new(C)
    c.GetName()
    c.Func1()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/1X7yiQeie8F

My question:
c.Func1() will lead to:
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

My scenario is:
user needs to implement some basic interfaces of A, and then user can use the member function of B. I hope that complicate codes are encapsulated into the member function of B, and user just need to provide basic infos.
How to achieve this goal?

Comment: Haiving created an instance of `C`, you never assign to `A` it embeds, and so it stays at the value it gets initialized with when the program created that instance of `C` — the zero value for the type `A`. The zero value for any interface type is `nil`. An attempt to call a method on the `nil` receiver crashes your program.

Comment: Your description of the question is not using common Go terms, so I find it confusing. I cannot be sure of what you want, but this might be what you desire: https://play.golang.org/p/OuHUoEN3k8u .

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to reproduce typical OOP designs in Go, which will lead to a great deal of frustration and unreadable code. For example, receivers in Go should not be named `this`. I would recommend discarding any OOP notions and re-thinking your design using Go idioms. Take a look at [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) for a good starting point.

Comment: @leafbebop Thanks so much. That's what I want.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for you suggestion. I'll read the `Effective Go` carefully.

Answer (score -1):

I see your code looping forever `GetName` calling duplicate

you can see my code

```js
package main

import "fmt"

type A interface {
    GetName() string
}

type B struct {
    A
}

func (this *B) Func1() {

}

type C struct {
    B
}

func (this *C) GetName() string {
    return "hello"
}

func main() {
    var c = new(C)
    fmt.Println(c.GetName())
}
```

```
https://play.golang.org/p/PaFd-BS9sdP
```